# Error when installing python packages in dockerfile (qt5, pyqt5)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install some packages into my docker environment so I can use them inside a container. But when I am running my Dockerfile I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qt5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for qt5
```

Can someone please help me with this problem?

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install qt5
RUN pip3 install pyqt5

COPY ./server.py /app/

COPY ./hinto.py /app/
```

**Note:** I already have those packages successfully running on my host machine (Macbook m1)

Answer (score 0):

From
https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/

> The GPL version of PyQt5 can be installed from PyPI:

Install it using:

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

Comment: Its not working, the error is when running the pip3 install qt5 command not the pyqt5. But I changed it anyway